# Setting "Keep window thumbnails" to always in KDE "breaks minimization"? How?

Tags: linux, kde, kwin, desktop-effects, compositing

KDE's Desktop effects (compositing) has a setting for when to keep window thumbnails. It says that setting this to always "breaks minimization". Does anyone know *how* it breaks minimization?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to be able to draw the windows (offscreen) so that it can create the thumbnails, KWin just shows them as minimized, while they aren't really.

So, the windows get minimized, as far as the user can tell, but they aren't really.

This could produce problems with applications that want to know whether they are minimized or not, but in reality, you shouldn't have any problems by choosing this option.

Comment: So the only way this would cause a problem is if an application wanted to take certain actions based on whether or not it is currently minimized?

Comment: That should be right. I've enabled that since KWin got compositing support, and I haven't had any issues yet.

Answer (score 0):

SDL apps get minimize/restore events with "Keep window thumbnails" on as of at least KDE 5.20:

```
// g++ main.cpp `pkg-config --cflags --libs sdl2`
#include <SDL.h>
#include <iostream>

#define CASE_STR( value ) case value: return #value; 
const char* sdlGetWindowEventString( Uint8 event )
{
    switch( event )
    {
    CASE_STR( SDL_WINDOWEVENT_NONE            )
    CASE_STR( SDL_WINDOWEVENT_SHOWN           )
    CASE_STR( SDL_WINDOWEVENT_HIDDEN          )
    CASE_STR( SDL_WINDOWEVENT_EXPOSED         )
    CASE_STR( SDL_WINDOWEVENT_MOVED           )
    CASE_STR( SDL_WINDOWEVENT_RESIZED         )
    CASE_STR( SDL_WINDOWEVENT_SIZE_CHANGED    )
    CASE_STR( SDL_WINDOWEVENT_MINIMIZED       )
    CASE_STR( SDL_WINDOWEVENT_MAXIMIZED       )
    CASE_STR( SDL_WINDOWEVENT_RESTORED        )
    CASE_STR( SDL_WINDOWEVENT_ENTER           )
    CASE_STR( SDL_WINDOWEVENT_LEAVE           )
    CASE_STR( SDL_WINDOWEVENT_FOCUS_GAINED    )
    CASE_STR( SDL_WINDOWEVENT_FOCUS_LOST      )
    CASE_STR( SDL_WINDOWEVENT_CLOSE           )
    CASE_STR( SDL_WINDOWEVENT_TAKE_FOCUS      )
    CASE_STR( SDL_WINDOWEVENT_HIT_TEST        )
    //CASE_STR( SDL_WINDOWEVENT_ICCPROF_CHANGED )
    //CASE_STR( SDL_WINDOWEVENT_DISPLAY_CHANGED )
    default: return "Unknown";
    }
}
#undef CASE_STR

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING );
    SDL_Window* window = SDL_CreateWindow
        (
        "SDL2",
         SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
         640, 480,
         SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN | SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE
        );
    

    bool running = true;
    while( running )
    {
        SDL_Surface* surface = SDL_GetWindowSurface( window );
        SDL_FillRect( surface, nullptr, SDL_MapRGB( surface->format, 127, 127, 127 ) );
        SDL_UpdateWindowSurface( window );

        SDL_Event ev;
        if( SDL_WaitEvent( &ev ) )
        {
            if( ( SDL_QUIT == ev.type ) ||
                ( SDL_KEYDOWN == ev.type && SDL_SCANCODE_ESCAPE == ev.key.keysym.scancode ) )
            {
                running = false;
                break;
            }
            
            if( SDL_WINDOWEVENT == ev.type )
            {
                std::cout << sdlGetWindowEventString( ev.window.event );
                std::cout << '\n';
            }
        }
        
    }

    SDL_DestroyWindow( window );
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

During a minimize/restore cycle watch for:

- `SDL_WINDOWEVENT_HIDDEN`
- `SDL_WINDOWEVENT_MINIMIZED`
- `SDL_WINDOWEVENT_RESTORED`
- `SDL_WINDOWEVENT_SHOWN`